# Get Activity Context within class which extends Application in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-view, android-context

Dear Folks,
              I am currently working on a android app where I need to show the progress dialog. I need to have a context object for this. 
This task I am implementing in the class which extends the application. But every time when I tried to access context object it is showing me the [`WindowManager.BadTokenException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.BadTokenException.html) for this line

```
Dialog dialog=ProgressDialog.show(getApplicationContext(), "Status", "Downloading The master");
```

Please help me where I am doing wrong

Edit:
 Below is my code!

```
public class FlightStatus extends Application {
    private Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();



        SharedPreferences preference=getSharedPreferences("FlightStatus", 1);
        if(preference.getBoolean("firstLaunch", true))
            {

                try {
                    Dialog dialog=ProgressDialog.show(getApplicationContext(), "Status!", "Downloading The master!!");
                    XLSReadHelper excelReader=new XLSReadHelper(getApplicationContext());
                    //excelReader.readExcelFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/UHCPAudit/cases.xls");  
                    excelReader.readExcelFile();
                    Log.d("Excel Operation ", "records read!!");
                    preference.edit().putBoolean("firstLaunch", false).commit();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    Log.d("Excel Operation ", e.getMessage());
                }

            }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is incorrect to try getting `Context` inside `Application`, as no `Activity` is yet initialized at this stage. Instead show your dialog from `Activity`/`Fragment`.

If you are showing the progress dialog from an `Activity`, use:

```
Dialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, "Status", "Downloading The master");
```

If you are showing it from a `Fragment`, then first add this member to your `Fragment` class:

```
private Activity activity;
```

Then call this in your `onCreateView()` method:

```
activity = getActivity();
```

and finally

```
Dialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "Status", "Downloading The master");
```

Comment: Hi cerebro , I am accessing from the class which extends Application!

Comment: When you are starting this class from the activity then at that time you can also pass the context and you can use the context easily..

Comment: @nsm: how are you invoking the method ??

Comment: I have mentioned in the android manifest file for application tag , the name of the application class and in oncreate of the same i am writing this line

Comment: @nsm please add your code with manifest I think you are doing something wrong in the coding

Comment: @ZygoteInit this is not correct , as I was referring to Application class which will be opened very first time  before even the activity being called. I cannot get activity context here! After lot of work around I found that We cannot show Dialog in the Application class!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a constructor which takes the Activity as context

```
public class YourClass extends Application{
    private Activity context;

    public YourClass(Activity context){
       this.context = context;
    }
}
```

And then from your calling `Activity`:

```
YourClass yourClass = new YourClass(this);
```

You can also try to use the `ProgressDialog` in your `Activity`itself, in a method which you can call from your custom class:

```
public void showProgress(){
  //Your progress code
}
```

And in your custom class:

```
context.showProgress();
```

Comment: @nsm I have made an edit with another suggestion to try.